# "Require" or "Need"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I thought that the two verbs "**require**" and "**need**" mean the same thing, while I saw these links: [link 1](https://www.englishcurrent.com/grammar/difference-need-require-verbs/) and [link 2](https://www.grammaring.com/to-infinitive-or-gerund-need-require-want).

Now, I don't think these two verbs are always the same. (Though I have my doubts about it.)

I wonder if you could help me understand where I can/cannot use them as a substitute for the other one?

In order to inquire about it, I have provided some examples. Please let me know which word works in each case?

> 1) If you want to be a successful teacher you will ................ patience.

a. require 
b. need

> 2) I'm thirsty. I ............... a glass of water.

a. require 
b. need

> 3) I ............. to speak to you before his arrival.

a. require 
b. need

> 4) They ........... the information to be sent as soon as possible.

a. required 
b. needed

Comment: Often the two verbs are synonymous, but given just *They **need / require** X* with no further context, I'd say one likely difference is that if they ***require*** something, *they usually know this* (often with the implication that they are *forcefully demanding* that X be provided by some underling or supplier). But with ***need*** it might be that even if X is in fact ***necessary*** in their specific circumstances, *they don't (yet) realise this.*

Comment: ...thus to some extent we could distinguish *I need a glass of water* as a "statement of fact" (it's essential that I have water), from *I require a glass of water* as a "peremptory demand" (you must give me water).

Comment: "They require the information to be sent as soon as possible." is not idiomatic. Is this teaching book written by a native speaker? It should be: **They needed the information sent as soon as possible**. **not**: to be sent. **Generally speaking**, people need things and situations require them.

Comment: Sometimes people say 'need' when they actually mean 'want'

Comment: Thank you all, but still it is a little vague for me! Based on what you put here, I can use both. But what difference each verb can make in each case (aside from the example #2 which @FumbleFingers explained it well.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference, and they are not always interchangeable.

In the most basic context, either are ok:

> - I require a screwdriver.
> - I need a screwdriver.

The difference is that "require" is far more "matter of fact" than "need", which is used where there is a more human, emotional context.

For example:

> I need some company.

This suggests you have an *emotional* need, and "require" would sound far too robotic in this context.

---

Your examples:

> If you want to be a successful teacher you <s>will</s> need patience.

Either would probably work here, but I prefer "need". A "requirement" tends to refer to something that needs fulfilling *once*, otherwise one normally specifies that it is a *regular requirement*. A "need" seems more suited for something constant, or ongoing. I found the word "will" unnecessary in this context as it seems to be an immediate need.

> I'm thirsty. I need a glass of water.

Again, either could work - "require" just sounds too robotic. Even though food and drink are daily "requirements", the fact that you talk about being "thirsty" which is a *feeling* makes "need" seem more suitable.

> I need to speak to you before his arrival.

"Require" doesn't interchange in this context. We don't say "require *to...*" - we would say "I have a requirement to..." In a formal setting, you could  perhaps say "I require a word with you before his arrival".

> They require the information to be sent as soon as possible.

Either would work - and perhaps "need" would be most people's choice as it is common, informal speech. As an example of where "require" does work though, this is a good one because somebody else's requirement is being passed on second hand, which is very distant and emotionless.

Comment: In terms of grammatical rules, could you say the rule is you can use either "need" or "require" unless it precedes a verb, in which case you can only use "need"?
In your examples, "need" and "require" were both fine except when you say "to speak" afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply.

**Require** is when someone or a situation needs something that is mandatory to have. Something that it can't do without. A must-have quality or maybe a very important piece of information.

**Need** is more simple. You just need something, plain and simple. You don't care about the quality of what you need. You just need it.

**Just a quick note**: You will hardly see **require** being used by native speakers in a day-to-day conversation as in "I **require** to speak to you". **Require** is more commonly used by companies, hiring managers, situations, jobs and etc...

Comment: The reason native speakers don't say "I require to speak to you" is mainly because the syntax of ***need*** and ***require*** are different (the latter generally requires an actual *noun* as its "object", not a verb-based clause). Note the shift of emphasis between *I **am required** to attend the meeting* (almost certainly at the behest of someone else) and *I **need** to attend the meeting* (feasibly, *for my own benefit*, despite not having been asked / ordered to attend).

Answer (score -1):

Require is a chosen restriction or policy imposed with thought and some element of fore-planning. It can be changed if desired to do so. There is little grey area to this term. A need is by nature, simplistic, and not optional.

Comment: Could you address OP's examples? How could you apply your response to OP's sentences? You can cite dictionaries to support your answer. See the [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/36187) for more tips.